# Activate Virtual environment using c#

Tags: python, c#, anaconda

Is it possible to activate virtual environment created without using the anaconda prompt?
For instance, I want to activate my virtual environment in c# in order to execute my python code.

This is my current code

```
private void CallPython()
    {
        // 1) Create Process Info
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = @"C:\Anaconda3\envs\MTCNN\python.exe"; 

        // 2) Provide script and arguments

        //THERMAL CAMERA
        var script = @"D:\Dekstop\thermal_MTCNN.py";


        psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\"";
     
        // 3) Process configuration
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        // 4) Execute process and get output

       var process = Process.Start(psi);
        process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

It seems like my python code cannot be executed because the virtual environment is not activated.
Has anyone knows how to activate the environment without using the prompt?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error but I'm also not getting any output.

Comment: I know for sure that the code is working with other python code because I tried it in using just the simple python interpreter generated by the pycharm (the python.exe located at venv/Scripts) and it execute perfectly. But with this kind of python code that needs the virtual env to be activated, It doesn't output anything.

Comment: Have you tried executing another helloworld.py style script to ensure you’re capturing output correctly?

Comment: Yes. I tried executing helloworld.py then pass it to windowsform label and it was a success. but in helloworld.py, it only uses an common python interpreter. In short, it does not need to be activated so it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this but I still have to open a command prompt.

First, I created a console project in visual studio. Then, I turned the console into Windows application by going to the project's properties and change the output type to Windows Application.  After that change your code from

```
class ProjectTitle
```

to

```
public partial class ProjectTitle : Form
```

then rebuild the project. This will then turn your program.cs to Windows Form application.

Run your generated Windows Form using this code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Program());
    }
```

then create a constructor to initialize components of windows form, hence adding this code

```
public Program()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then, you could now create your windows form design like a normal windows form like dragging and dropping of the tools (buttons, etc)

And to answer my question, here's how to activate virtual environment using C#

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("activate virtualenvName");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\PathWhereYourPythonIsLocated");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("python hello.py");
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

So there it is! The reason why I did this is because I want my output to be embedded with C# Winform's picturebox. I'm kinda new to python and c# embedding so I hope this one helps

Comment: Aka. the key is to launch it through a shell program.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use virtualenv or anything
Use embedded python zip.
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-31010/

Steps to use python are:

1. Extract the zip.
2. Type `get-pip.py` on google and download fom the link
   https://bootstrap.pypa.io › get-pip
3. Place the `get-pip.py` inside where the `python.exe` is.
4. Open `python<version>._pth` file and uncomment  the import statement.
5. Use `path/to/python.exe -m pip install <your-package>`
6. Now you can use this python to run anything